# Analog of C++ structured binding in C#

Tags: c#, initialization

in C++17 there is a very nifty feature called structured binding. I have difficulty finding its C# analog. Specifically, my code looks something like:

```
public struct A
{
public int up;
public int down;
public int left;
public int right;
};
public abstract A foo();
A a = foo();
int up=a.up;
int down=a.down;
int left=a.left;
int right=a.right;
```

and I want to initialize these variables in a less verbose way.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're probably looking for [deconstructing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct).

Comment: The closest thing would be using Reflection to get fetch your struct's values in a loop, but that would probably be *more* verbose. I cannot think of any thing else in C# that works that way, and I'll bet C++ does it via some sort of BitBlt/block transfer; if so, that kind of thing is completely foreign to C#.

Comment: You might consider MemberwiseClone, implemented by default in every class and struct. That is similar to your request, but will not give you individual variables to manipulate, merely a copy of the original struct (provided you cast it to A from the default *object* data type).

Comment: @Lev - I was going solely on your example so I wasn't sure (I'm not current on C++), but I'm pretty sure now. In [this page's first example](https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/structured-bindings/), the statement `auto [x,y,z] = f();` in C++ would be `var (x,y,z) = f();` in C#.  Deconstructing is definitely what you want. Just keep in mind that it's not as out-of-the-box in C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```cs
using System;

public struct A
{
    public int up;
    public int down;
    public int left;
    public int right;
    
    public void Deconstruct(out int up, out int down, out int left, out int right)
    {
        up = this.up;
        down = this.down;
        left = this.left;
        right = this.right;
    }
};

public static class M {
    public static void main() {
        var (up,down,left,right) = new A();
    }
}
```

or in C# 10:

```cs
using System;

record struct A(int up, int down, int left, int right);

public static class M {
    public static void main() {
        var (up,down,left,right) = new A();
    }
}
```